# Replace combination of space, hyphen and text or a "by" using regex and pandas

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace a combination of a space, an hyphen, a space and text or the combination "By [Author]". This is my data frame:

```
my_titles = ['Peter Rabbit - Volume II', 'Who stole my cookie  By Cole Pattesh', 'The Stormy Night -  Nia Costas']
adf = pd.DataFrame({'my_titles':my_titles})
adf
    my_titles
0   Peter Rabbit - Volume II
1   Who stole my cookie By Cole Pattesh
2   The Stormy Night - Nia Costas
```

My expected df is:

```
    my_titles
0   Peter Rabbit
1   Who stole my cookie
2   The Stormy Night
```

I have tried this, expecting regex to recognize the '\s' space and the '|' (or):

```
adf['my_titles'].replace('\s-\s*|\sBy\s*$','',regex=True)
adf
```

And I tried this too trying to chain the space and words:

```
adf['my_titles'].replace('[ - \w]|[ By \w]','',regex=True)
adf
```

Please, do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Break your problem down by seeing if a regex you write works for just one case at a time. Fix that first, then you can add the or component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
my_titles = ['Peter Rabbit - Volume II', 'Who stole my cookie  By Cole Pattesh', 'The Stormy Night -  Nia Costas']
adf = pd.DataFrame({'my_titles':my_titles})
adf['my_titles'] = adf['my_titles'].str.replace(r'\s+(?:-\s+|By\s+[A-Z]).*', '', regex=True)
```

Ouput of `print(adf['my_titles'])`:

```py
0           Peter Rabbit
1    Who stole my cookie
2       The Stormy Night
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmL673/1). *Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:-\s+|By\s+[A-Z])` - a `-` and one or more whitespaces, or `By`, one or more whitespaces, and an uppercase letter
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew, the `?:` is new for me (in the regex demo it says it's for non-capturing group) and it was interesting to first capture the ` - ` or `By `. Today I learned something new. Again, thank you!